# Django: Custom widget for ForeignKey in geolocation app

Tags: python, django, geolocation, widget, foreign-keys

I am working on an application that manage the locations for a web site. This application (locations) contains the model(simplified):

```
class Location(models.Model):
    """ Model for storing locations, places and addresses """

    address = models.CharField(_('address'), max_length=100, blank=True)
    """ Location address """

    latitude = models.FloatField(_('latitude'), blank = True)
    """ Latitude info point """

    longitude = models.FloatField(_('longitude'), blank = True)
    """ Longitude info point """
```

So that other applications and models who want to store a location, actually contain a ForeignKey to this model.
In addition, the locations application, defines a widget that instead of displaying the typical select associated with ForeignKey fields, renders a google map supported by a javascript that saves the latitude, longitude, and address in a HiddenInput field(also simplified):

```
class LocationEditWidget(HiddenInput):

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        default_attrs = {}

        if attrs:
            default_attrs.update(attrs)
        super(LocationEditWidget, self).__init__(default_attrs)



    class Media:
        js = (
                'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true',
                'js/gmaps.js',
                'js/location-select.js',
            )

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        self.attrs['id']            = self.attrs.get('id', 'unique')
        self.attrs['latitude']      = self.attrs.get('latitude', 'auto')
        self.attrs['longitude']     = self.attrs.get('longitude', 'auto')
        self.attrs['geocoding']     = self.attrs.get('geocoding', 'True')
        self.attrs['geolocation']   = self.attrs.get('geolocation', 'True')
        self.attrs['width']         = self.attrs.get('width', '400')
        self.attrs['height']        = self.attrs.get('height', '400')

        output = super(LocationEditWidget, self).render(name, '%s,%s,%s' % (value.latitude, value.longitude, value.address), attrs)
        map_html = render_to_string('./select_location.html',
                                {
                                    "id"                : self.attrs['id'],
                                    "geocoding_button"  : self.attrs['geocoding'],
                                    "geolocation_button": self.attrs['geolocation'],
                                    "latitude"          : self.attrs['latitude'],
                                    "longitude"         : self.attrs['longitude'],
                                    "width"             : self.attrs['width'],
                                    "height"            : self.attrs['height']
                                })

        return mark_safe(output+map_html)
```

The idea is that any other model that need to work with locations, has a ForeignKey field associated with the Location model, for example:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    """
    `Events` main model.
    """

    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=100, blank=True)
    """ Title. """

    place = models.ForeignKey(Location, verbose_name=_('place'), related_name="place", blank=True)
    """ Location. """

    meeting_point = models.ForeignKey(Location, verbose_name=_('place'), related_name="meeting_point", blank=True)
    """ Meeting Point """

    duration = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('duration days'), blank=True)
    """ Duration, specified in days. """

    price = models.DecimalField(_('price'), max_digits=7,  decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    """ Price. """
```

So when you send the form (apart from save conventionally all the other model fields),  a new Location object will be created with the provided location information (latitude, longitude and address) and it will be stored in the database. Finally establishing the relationship with the ForeignKey field ("place" in the previous model) using this new Location object.

For now, the widget works correctly and renders the map instead of the typical select widget, besides filling the HiddenInput with latitude, longitude and direction.

In my events/forms.py:

```
class NewEventForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def save(self):

        value = self.data['place'].split(',');
        location = Location(latitude=value[0], longitude=value[1], address=value[2:])
        self.instance.place = location

        new_event = super(NewEventForm, self).save(commit=False)
        new_event.save()

        return new_offer

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('title', 'duration', 'price', 'place')
        widgets = {
                    'place': LocationEditWidget(),
                   }
```

and in my events/views.py:

```
@login_required
def event_new(request):
    new_event = Event(price=0, owner=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Form submited
        Event_form = NewEventForm(request.POST, instance=new_event)

        if event_form.is_valid():
            # Form succesfully validated
            event_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/Event/%s/edit' % new_event.id) 

    else:
        # Initial form
        event_form = NewEventForm(instance=new_event)

    return render_to_response(  'events/event_new.html',
                                {'event_form':event_form},
                                context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But I am new to Django and I have some problems to understand the relationships between widgets, forms, fields and form fields. The problem is that the form does not validate correctly and if I force validation (bypasing 'event_form.is_valid ()') I get an error when saving to the database. On the other hand does not seem quite right (Because of DRY) having to subclassing a ModelForm for each application/model that uses locations.

Do I need to create custom fields and custom form fields?
Any ideas as how to orient it? 
Can I use a widget to a ForeingKey?

Thanks in advance and please forgive me for my poor English.